# Searching for multiple FROM addresses using imapclient.IMAPClient.search in python

Tags: python, imap

I have been searching but it looks as if the syntax has changed since the posts I have found have been posted. I am trying to find emails from multiple addresses. This works:

```
UIDs = conn.search([
                      ['FROM','foo@bar.com'],
                      [u'SINCE', datetime.date(2022, 3, 6)],
])
```

I was hoping for something like this:

```
UIDs = conn.search([
                      'OR'[
                      ['FROM','foo@bar.com'],['FROM','eggs@spam.com']
                      ],
                      [u'SINCE', datetime.date(2022, 3, 6)],
])
```

But I can't seem to find any variation of OR that works. I have tried an example from Automate the boring stuff, and he recommends this:

```
imapObj.search(['OR FROM alice@example.com FROM bob@example.com']
```

This doesn't work for me either.
I've checked imapclient page and don't find the answer there either:
https://imapclient.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: `OR FROM alice@example.com FROM bob@example.com` is the correct syntax.  To be sure you can try `OR (FROM "alice@example.com") (FROM "bob@example.com")`.  However, it's quite possible your server software does not actually support the IMAP search language properly.  What server are you using?

Comment: @Max I tried this: 
`UIDs=conn.search(['OR (FROM alice@example.com) (FROM bob@example.com)'])` and it gives me the following error:
This error may have been caused by a syntax error in the criteria: ['OR (FROM alice@example.com) (FROM bob@example.com)']
Please refer to the documentation for more information about search criteria syntax..
https://imapclient.readthedocs.io/en/master/#imapclient.IMAPClient.search

I'm using Python 3.8.8, imapclient 2.2.0, pyzmail 1.0.4, connecting to imap.gmail.com

Comment: Why are you using [ ]?  Is that part of imapclient?  Just send the raw string, including with quotes. `conn.search('OR (FROM "alice@example.com") (FROM "bob@example.com")'`.  (Update: Ah, I see, imapclient uses slightly different syntax from imaplib, if you pass a raw string, it will use it raw.  I would try that)

Comment: @Max
It seems to be part of the syntax:
`messages = server.search(['FROM', 'best-friend@domain.com'])`, from [library documentation](https://imapclient.readthedocs.io/en/2.2.0/).

If I use your technique, I get the following error:<br>
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

I can't paste the full error here unfortunately, but it would seem as if this just isn't possible based on the error response.

Comment: https://imapclient.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#imapclient.IMAPClient.search says you can send a 'simple string' to do a raw search: `It is also possible (but not recommended) to pass the combined criteria as a single string. In this case IMAPClient won’t perform quoting, allowing lower-level specification of criteria.`  Though you'd better make sure all you rbrackets and such match up!

Comment: @Max you are a legend. This did the trick:
`searchstring='OR (FROM "alice@example.com") (FROM "bob@example.com")'
UIDs=conn.search(searchstring)`

Seems like a silly workaround but I'm so glad it works!

Side note: what is the etiquette - do I allow you to post the answer and then I upvote?

Comment: uh, sure.   I'm not quite sure what the proper imapclient way to do it is, but I can give my workaround as an answer.  Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with the imapclient library, but I see that the [API](https://imapclient.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#imapclient.IMAPClient.search) allows sending raw strings, so if it's not sending exactly what you want, you can override it.

This should do it for you, making it as unambiguous as possible:

```
conn.search('OR (FROM "alice@example.com") (FROM "bob@example.com")')
```